# Sort NSArray by 'Date' Element of included NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

Here's what I have:
An `NSMutableArray` that holds several `NSDictionary` Objects.
Each `NSDictionary` has a Date String as an Element.

Here's my loop that prints out the Date in each `NSDictionary`

```
[dateFormatterIn setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss\n"];
[dateFormatterOut setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];     

for(NSMutableDictionary *thisStory in stories){
        id fromDate = [thisStory objectForKey:@"from_time"];
        id date = [dateFormatterIn dateFromString:fromDate];
        NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatterOut stringFromDate:date]);
    }
```

Does anyone have a clue how I can sort my array `stories` by date?
I am quite new to objective C.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Using the your stories array's sortUsingDescriptor method should do the trick:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"from_time" ascending: YES] autorelease];
[stories sortUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: This wpuld be my preference, or you can use sortUsingSelector and add a compare to your story class

Comment: My array did not sort with this code I try to compare NSDate property any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume Following  data structure : array variable name: **collectionArray** =
`[
  {
    date: "01-02-2015 02:01",
    value: 1,
    name: "rajan"
  },
  {
    date: "01-02-2014 02:01",
    value: 11,
    name: "rajan1"
  },
  {
    date: "01-02-2012 02:01",
    value: 111,
    name: "rajan2"
  }
]`

Now to sort  this array of nsdictionary by date we follow the following steps

`NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];

```
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[collectionArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {

    NSString *d1Str =[obj1 valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSString *d2Str =[obj2 valueForKey:@"date"]

    NSString *d1Timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[formatter dateFromString:d1Str] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSString *d2Timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[formatter dateFromString:d2Str] timeIntervalSince1970]];

    return [d2Timestamp compare:d1Timestamp options:NSNumericSearch]; // descending order


}] mutableCopy];`
```